# I can make a modal disappear, but I can't make it appear

Tags: javascript, css, simplemodal

I have this piece of code in JavaScript that tries to change the property in CSS "visibility: hidden;" for "visibility: none;" with a click of a button

```
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){modal.style.visibility = "none";})
```

This code can make the modal disappear, but can't make it appear

Here it is the modal CSS properties:

```
#modal{
    margin: 5px 20px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: darkgreen;
    align-items: center;
    border: 4px solid darkgreen;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Plz add the html.

Comment: See [MDN for the valid values for `visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility has 2 valid values:

- `hidden`: Hide the element
- `visible`: Show the element

If you want your element to appear on-click: You need to change  to use `visible`:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function(){modal.style.visibility = "visible";})
```

Furthermore, I suggest you use the `display` property instead:

- `block`: Show the element
- `none`: Hide the element

Extra reading: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)